# Unrecognized Quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers, lambda-calculus

Which quantifiers are represented by the first two symbols ($\iota$ and $\mathcal{A}$) in the set in which Q belongs. I could not find a reference on the [Quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)) Wikipedia article.

[image]

*(Source: Introductory slide on Lambda Calculus (slide 32) in a [slide-deck](http://yoavartzi.com//pub/afz-tutorial.acl.2013.pdf#page=32) on grammars for parsing natural language sentences.)*

Here's an example where the first one is used; might be helpful to pin-point which quantifier it represents in case the author used non-standard symbols.

[image]

*(Source: Slide 45 in the same [slide-deck](http://yoavartzi.com//pub/afz-tutorial.acl.2013.pdf#page=45).)*

Comment: Interesting. I don't recognize them either.

Comment: Other than $\forall$ and $\exists$, the most common quantifiers that are used are "there exists a unique", "there does not exist", and "not all". Those would be my list of probable candidates.

Comment: The first one could be "for infinitely many" and the second could be "for all but finitely many" but I am just guessing.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)#Other_quantifiers

Comment: @Browning, they do not seem to be the ones you are guessing based on an example usage of the first quantifier I just added to the question.

Comment: $\iota x.\phi(x)$ is not a quantifier in the sense that it creates a statement, but rather an object, namly that (unique) $x$ for which $\phi(x)$ holds, hence $\iota$ cannot be used in place of $\mathcal Q$, I suppose. I hav no idea what $\mathcal A$ is, though.

Comment: @6005, based on the example usage I just added, "there exists a unique" seems to be a likely choice for the $\iota$ quantifier.

Comment: The *iota* is used in definite descriptions: $\iota x.F(x)$ is ‘the $x$ which is $F$’. If I remember correctly, it’s undefined if there is no unique entity with the specified property. This $\iota$ isn’t really a quantifier, since $\iota x.F(x)$ is actually a term. It can be applied when $\exists!x.F(x)$ is true and not otherwise. [This page](http://softoption.us/content/node/174) may be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iota ($\iota$) and script A ($\mathcal{A}$) are determiners, not quantifiers in the usual sense; they’re described later, in the slides titled **Definite Determiners** and **Indefinite Determiners**. The expression $\iota x.F(x)$ is a term representing the unique entity $x$ such that $F(x)$ is true when such an entity exists and is undefined otherwise; see also [this web page](http://softoption.us/content/node/174). $\mathcal{A}$ is the indefinite counterpart of $\iota$: $\mathcal{A}x.F(x)$ selects any entity $x$ such that $F(x)$ is true. Thus, $\iota$ functions somewhat like the definite article *the*, while $\mathscr{A}$ functions rather like the indefinite article *a(n)*. The examples in the relevant slides are fairly clear.